# how to embed variables in text file in C#

Tags: c#, nlp

I have a text file that has score of about  14000 words like below,

```
accomplished#a  0.28448
accomplishment#n    0.76255
accurate#a  0.60503
accurately#r    0.15754
achievable#a    0.15793
achievement#n   0.57006
acumen#n    0.17703
adaptable#a 0
adaptive#a  0.15793
```

currently I'm getting score of each word in query by matching each word in query with values in this text file that is external to program, for example, if sentence if "I accomplished it accurately" , it will retrieve score 0.28448 for accomplished and 0.15754 for accurately from text file.
But I think this is not proper way to do this, and it will more fast if I could define this values somewhere in my c# code or embed this text file permanently in my project. How can do this?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to make a numeric constant?

Comment: accomplished#a should work as string so I can match it with word "accomplished" in any query at same time it should assign its float score to accomplished . Currently to extract word value pair from file I'm using regEx .

Comment: so will it be good idea to define 14000 variables in code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th proper way is to load this file once in a `Dictionary<string, int>` , possibly at the startup of the application.

Then look up your words in the dictionary to retrieve their scores. This will be very efficient, even for a large number of words.

Comment: ok I did it. Looks better than earlier . But still further is there someway I can hold this dictionary permanently in code without having to create every time program loads, coz this data is static and wont change.

Comment: Well, you can hardcode everything and load it in a dictionary as well (instead of reading the file), but it sounds like a very bad design decision (what if you need to change a score ? you need to recompile / redeploy ?)